# spring integration publish subscribe between beans

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Thanks for reading ahead of time. In my main method I have a PublishSubscribeChannel

```
@Bean(name = "feeSchedule")
public SubscribableChannel getMessageChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}
```

In a service that does a long running process it creates a fee schedule that I inject the channel into

```
@Service
public class FeeScheduleCompareServiceImpl implements FeeScheduleCompareService {

    @Autowired
    MessageChannel outChannel;

    public List<FeeScheduleUpdate> compareFeeSchedules(String oldStudyId) {
    List<FeeScheduleUpdate> sortedResultList = longMethod(oldStudyId);
    outChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(sortedResultList).build());
        return sortedResultList;
    } 
}
```

Now this is the part I'm struggling with. I want to use completable future and get the payload of the event in the future A in another spring bean. I need future A to return the payload from the message. I think want to create a ServiceActivator to be the message end point but like I said, I need it to return the payload for future A.

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class SFCCCompareServiceImpl implements SFCCCompareService {
     @Autowired
    private SubscribableChannel outChannel;

     @Override
    public List<SFCCCompareDTO> compareSFCC(String state, int service){
    ArrayList<SFCCCompareDTO> returnList = new ArrayList<SFCCCompareDTO>();
    CompletableFuture<List<FeeScheduleUpdate>> fa =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () ->
            {  //block A   WHAT GOES HERE?!?!
                    outChannel.subscribe()
            }
    );
    CompletableFuture<List<StateFeeCodeClassification>> fb =  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () ->
            {  
                  return this.stateFeeCodeClassificationRepository.findAll();       
            }
    );
    CompletableFuture<List<SFCCCompareDTO>> fc = fa.thenCombine(fb,(a,b) ->{
        //block C
        //get in this block when both A & B are complete
        Object theList = b.stream().forEach(new Consumer<StateFeeCodeClassification>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(StateFeeCodeClassification stateFeeCodeClassification) {
                a.stream().forEach(new Consumer<FeeScheduleUpdate>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(FeeScheduleUpdate feeScheduleUpdate) {
                        returnList new SFCCCompareDTO();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return theList;
    });
    fc.join();
    return returnList;
}

}
```

Was thinking there would be a service activator like:

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class UpdatesHandler implements MessageHandler{

    @ServiceActivator(requiresReply = "true")
    public List<FeeScheduleUpdate> getUpdates(Message m){
        return (List<FeeScheduleUpdate>) m.getPayload();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, but I'll try to help you with some info.

Spring Integration doesn't provide `CompletableFuture` support, but it does provide an async handling and replies.

See [Asynchronous Gateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#async-gateway) for more information. And also see [Asynchronous Service Activator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#async-service-activator).

`outChannel.subscribe()` should come with the `MessageHandler` callback, by the way.

Comment: in the future A block, with my rx experience, I want to do something like 

return outChannel.subscribe( onNext( payload ->  return payload))

I want that future A block to return a of List<FeeScheduleUpdates> . Sounds like this won't work anyway. I looked in 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples
and didn't find anything exactly like that. If I supply subscribe( ) with a MessageHandler, how does that handler get the data in the callback to the return statement for future block A?

Comment: I don't have experience with `CompletableFuture` composition, so can't say how and what should be there. But you really could get some help from the `@MessagingGateway` which returns that for you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gw-completable-future